# Publishing status: Rejected : google plasy store review

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

It's a taxi hailing driver app that need to access location in the background. I added popup message as

> **APP NAME** app gathers your location data continuously, only starting from the moment you open it until you close it. This tracking occurs both when the app is in the foreground and in the background, particularly when you're on a trip and actively searching for passengers.
>
> This practice is in place to guarantee your availability to passengers, facilitating pickups, drop-offs, and customer support, all while maintaining a focus on safety.
>
> Rest assured that your location data will solely be employed for these specific reasons and will not be disclosed to external entities.

This dialog is displayed as Prominent disclosure to tell the app is need to access user background location. But **Google play reject it**.

[Google rejection message is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3h9.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you click the screenshot references to see if you followed the guidelines properly?

Comment: In Google's message focus on point 2.1: "Your prominent disclosure must appear before ... runtime permission". The flow in your app should be: show the disclosure; if the user press "ok" request the runtime permission; if the user "cancel" don't request the runtime permission.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the dialog at the start of the app straight away, even if user hasn't logged in / sign in yet ? Maybe to bypass that you should show that dialog only after logged in, or when you are showing your map to be picked up.
Even if you put a rich description, I think as a user it might be too soon to get his own current location when not needed.